# Remove Horizontal Overscroll Effect on a Vertical Column Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Column in compose which uses the vertical scroll modifier.

For some reason it has a horizontal overscroll effect when there is no horizontal content in addition to the vertical overscroll effect.

I just want the vertical overscroll effect.

Does anyone know how to remove the horizontal overscroll effect?

```
        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(
                rememberScrollState()
            )
        ) {
            SearchBar(toSearch = toSearch)
            Divider(dp = 8)
            DefaultListItems(
                toPastPurchases = toPastPurchases,
                toListsAndFavorites = toListsAndFavorites,
                toCollection = toDepartment,
                toRecipe = toRecipe,
                exploreViewModel = viewModel
            )...
```